# “reach no bounds” vs. “know no bounds”

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I know that *know no bounds* actually means “have no bounds”, “exist with no limits”. For example,

> “His self-glorification *knew no bounds*”

can mean he may have thought that there’s no hero too glorious, no god too mighty to escape the comparison with him.

But, my question is if

> “His self-glorification *reached no bounds*”

means the very same thing. Or could it mean that he might be a quite modest man, not with too much ego, that he never went beyond the bounds?

**PS:** I have never met “reach no bounds”, that’s just my guess. Is it odd to be used by a native speaker? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are correct, **reached no bounds** is not idiomatic.  To **know no bounds** is to go beyond the boundaries or constraints that others recognize.  There was no limit to his self-glorification.

Answer (score 2):

"Knew no bounds" is an old-fashioned set phrase meaning "had no bounds (or limit)". It simply means that. The verb "know" can be replaced with "have" to produce a modern equivalent. Other phrases of this type:

know no fear: have no fear

know no shame: have no shame

"Reached no bounds" is not a natural English phrase used by native speakers.

Comment: It doesn't really sound old-fashioned to me. What's your source for that claim?

Comment: OK maybe "formal" would be better - https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/know-no-bounds

Comment: I'd probably say it sounds "literary."  I don't think I'd use it in casual conversation unless I was trying to evoke a caricature of a highly-educated (or perhaps over-educated) person.

Comment: @Canadian Yankee - exactly. In writing it would seem pompous and overdone, as if the writer were reaching for some olde-worlde flavour, or simply wanted to seem erudite.